# sshd inactive (dead) even when connected via ssh

Tags: debian, ssh, systemd, sshd, systemctl

I'm running an VPS with Debian 11 on it.

I was noticing, that `systemctl status ssh` says the ssh deamon is `incative (dead)`. I have researched for quite a while and found out, that ssh uses something called "socket activation" (https://github.com/clearlinux/distribution/issues/72). That probably explains why systemd listens on port 22:

```
# lsof -i -P -n  | grep LISTEN | grep :22
systemd      1            root   46u  IPv6 32257361      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

However, as I understand it, the service should be at least shown as active, while I'm connected via ssh, right? It doesn't.

Furthermore, how do you `systemctl` does not accepts any reload request and just responds `ssh.service is not active, cannot reload.`
Also, how do I stop the service then?

My biggest problem is, that when I run `systemctl start ssh` the service is started and marked as `active (running)`. However, when I logout and try to relogin now via ssh it tells me `Connection reset by 46.*.*.* port 22`.

Thanks for any help of understanding this.

UPDATE:
After accessing my VPS over VNC I found out, that my ssh service failed because there was no `/run/sshd` directory. `# mkdir /run/sshd` fixed that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a separate `.socket` systemd unit responsible for SSH. It seems handling SSH this way [is not recommended anymore](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/OpenSSH#Daemon_management) and the package in sid has reverted back to the usual `.service` unit daemon.

To do that yourself manually, just disable/mask the `.socket` unit before enabling the `.service` unit.